# How to get the target cell row number in the sheet with Google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a google-apps-script in google sheet.

First I need get the target cell row number, then continue the next step.

I have tried the `getRow()`and `getRowIndex()`,all of them return 0, could you tell me what's the right method...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet1 = sheets[0];
var cell = sheet1.getActiveCell();
var SelectRow = cell.getRow();
Logger.log("SelectRow :" & SelectRow);
```

---

For Example:
[image: Example]

I want to return a number 2.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `Logger.log("SelectRow :" & SelectRow);`. Use `+` instead of `&`  for string concatenation and your variable will be displayed properly.

use:

`Logger.log("SelectRow :" + SelectRow);`

or this:

`Logger.log("SelectRow : %s", SelectRow);`

Comment: Thank you very much first, I try it just now, but always return 0, have you try it? Is the same result?

Comment: Know what? your code is also working.. the problem is Logger.log("Select Row :" & SelectRow); use + instead of & for string concatenation and it will show you the number of row instead of 0

Comment: You are right, I have found the same question too. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this -

```
var currRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
Logger.log("SelectRow :" & SelectRow);
```